# How to format JavaScript date to mm/dd/yyyy?

Tags: javascript

Im getting the date like 'Wed Nov 08 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)' and putting the value in an input.

Is there a way to parse the datetime into a date, add five days to it, and then format it like mm/dd/yyyy?

I made a https://jsfiddle.net/ax6qqw0t/

```js
startingDate = new Date(5/5/2017);
var adjustedDate = addDays(startingDate,13);
$('#max_products').val(adjustedDate);
```

Comment: You might consider a library like Moment.js for this.

Comment: If you're looking for high flexibility in human readable date formatting, you might want to check out the Moment.js library.

Comment: Related: [Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1056728/where-can-i-find-documentation-on-formatting-a-date-in-javascript)

Comment: wow i solve it with moment.js , can I still give credit to those who solve without it ?

Comment: That's the beauty of being a programmer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I format a date in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-do-i-format-a-date-in-javascript)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```js
var date = new Date('Mon Aug 14 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (CDT)');
var newdate= (date.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + date.getDate() + '/' +  date.getFullYear();
```

Comment: Is this really the correct answer? It does not have preceding zero for one digit month or day. Example that I get is `5/1/1993` and this is not mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 5):

Here are useful **one-liners** to get date string in various formats:

**US-Date formatted as m/d/yyyy and mm/DD/yyyy (padded zeroes)**

```
>new Date().toLocaleDateString(); //if your locale is US, otherwise toLocaleDateString('en-US');
"2/7/2020"
>new Date().toLocaleDateString('es-pa'); //zero-padded US date
"02/07/2020"
```

**Date formatted as yyyy-mm-dd, and yyyymmdd: useful for sorting**

```
>new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-ca');
"2020-02-07"
>new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-ca').replace(/-/g,'');
"20200207"
```

**This list covers most other international formats:**

```
d-M-yyyy        nl
dd.MM.yyyy      en-CH
d. M. yyyy      sk
d.MM.yyyy       pl
d.M.yyyy        de
dd/MM/yyyy      en-DE
d/MM/yyyy       en-NZ
d/M/yyyy        ca
d/M/yyyy        mr (devanagari numbers)
yyyy-M-d        bs
yyyy. MM. dd.   hu
yyyy. M. d.     ko-KP
yyyy/MM/dd      en-ZA
yyyy/MM/dd      ar-EG (arabic numbers)
yyyy/M/d        zh-CN
```

Finally, the ECMAScript Intl.DateTimeFormat is the Internationalization API that gives you lot of formatting flexibility. Here is a link to the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat

Comment: sorry, but toLocaleDateString does NOT seem to reliably produce m/d/yyyy or mm/dd/yyyy under nodejs for *any* arguments to pass that I can find.

Comment: Can you give me some example? I tested several dates in Node.js v18.16.0 and they gave me right formats every time.

Comment: You've got a newer version of nodejs than we are using in production.  From my research, apparently it's implementation dependant so the fact that it changed across the last 10 node versions isn't surprising.

Answer (score 3):

Just for fun, here's how you could do it with `moment.js`.

`moment('2017-05-05').add(13, 'day').format('MM/DD/YYYY');`

[fiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/pm710x9g/)

Answer (score 3):

I'm sure you've solved this by now, but it looked like a fun one so I decided to take a stab at it using `Intl.DateTimeFormat`.

```js
// get date for five days later
const dateText = 'Fri Dec 29 2017 00:00:00 GMT-0800 (Pacific Standard Time)';
const date = new Date(dateText);
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 5);

// set up date formatting parameters
const options = {year: 'numeric'};
options.month = options.day = '2-digit';

// print date to console
const dateFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat([], options);
console.log(dateFormat.format(date));
```

Comment: this should be the top answer